# Jhipster building docker image error with redis connection

Tags: jhipster

I am new in Jhipster community and the development platform looks very good !
But i got a problem to build the docker image for my local development.

I successfully generated my jhipster application, then i folow the documentation and tried to build docker image with (maven)

```
/mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild
```

And I keep looping over this error (for about 10mn, after that stops and says the build is failed)

```
2020-08-24 15:48:55.693  WARN 8388 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jCacheCacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'jCacheCacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManagerCustomizer' defined in class path resource [com/carcrypto/api/config/CacheConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManagerCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jcacheConfiguration' defined in class path resource [com/carcrypto/api/config/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.configuration.Configuration]: Factory method 'jcacheConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis server: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379
2020-08-24 15:48:55.698 ERROR 8388 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

We clearly see this : `RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis server: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379`

In the same time i can see redis container who is running in docker but not with port 6379, it is on port 32789 (looks like default available port for docker)...

I am on windows 10, someone already have this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of jhipster are you using? We had a bug when setting the properties for the redis testcontainer was not working.

Comment: @atomfrede I am using the version 6.10.1, this version is impacted by the bug ?

Comment: Yes. The problem is the RedisTestContainerExtension which uses Dynamic Properties, which is only working in test classes. You need to change the beforeAll implementation to set system properties. The correct code is here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/templates/src/test/java/package/RedisTestContainerExtension.java.ejs

Answer (score 1):

That is a but in the 6.10.1. It will be fixed in the upcoming 6.10.2 release (not yet released). Until that you need to change the `RedisTestContainerExtension` implementation.

It should look like this currently:

```java
public class RedisTestContainerExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

    private static AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private static GenericContainer redis;

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void redisProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("jhipster.cache.redis.server", () -> "redis://" + redis.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + redis.getMappedPort(6379));
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        if (!started.get()) {
            redis = new GenericContainer("redis:6.0.4").withExposedPorts(6379);
            redis.start();
            started.set(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the `DynamicPropertySource` which only works in test classes but not in junit extensions. SO you need to remove that and set a system property to overwrite the redis connection with the correct port from the container like this:

```java
public class RedisTestContainerExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

    private static AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private static GenericContainer redis = new GenericContainer("redis:6.0.4").withExposedPorts(6379);

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        if (!started.get()) {
            redis.start();
            System.setProperty(
                "jhipster.cache.redis.server",
                "redis://" + redis.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + redis.getMappedPort(6379)
            );
            started.set(true);
        }
    }
}
```